# Chapters in TeX

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titles

I've been writing in TeX for a few years, but this is my first time writing a long document.

I have always used `\title` for the main title, and `\section` for smaller titles. It seems that it is only possible to use `\title` once. I therefore wonder what the standard procedure is for a title that is between the main title and a section. In particular, what should I use for titles of chapters?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think (although you don't say) that you are using LaTeX with the`article` class. Switch to `report` or `book` class and then you will have a `\chapter` command.

Comment: I was using amsart. Let me try now.

Comment: @Nicole Have a look at `amsbook`.