# Numbering theorems within chapters

Tags: numbering, theorems

I've recently asked a question:
[Chapters in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53679/chapters-in-tex/53680#comment112219_53680)

regarding working with chapters in tex. I have since learned that I must use documentclass `report` for the purposes of my document. However, now all of my Theorems, Corollaries, Remarks, and so forth are numbered "0.number.number" (with the first 0 never changing). I would like, at the very least, to understand how to make the first number denote the number of the chapter.

The current code I have is this:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{qst}[thm]{Question}
\newtheorem{prp}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{hyp}[thm]{Hypotheses}
\newtheorem{crl}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{cnj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{dff}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{clm}[thm]{Claim}
\newtheorem{ntt}[thm]{Notation}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Comment: You probably also have section numbers staring with 0 that never changes. If so, you're probably not using `\chapter` at all. If you want to get rid of the chapter numbering, you could try `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\@gobble}\makeatother`. This is a very crude suggestion, but without more information it might work.

Comment: Change the line: `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` to `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]`

Comment: I see the problem now. I was using `\chapter*` rather than `\chapter`. Is there a way for me to still use `\chapter*` AND have the numbering?

Comment: @Nicole: Which numbering do you mean? chapter number? Why do you use chapter*?

Comment: @Nicole the only reason for using `\chapter*` rather than `\chapter` is to _avoid_ numbering. If you want numbers then you want `\chapter`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well, `\chapter*` avoids the title "Chapter (number of chapter)" in the beginning of every chapter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All LaTeX classes use the `\thechapter`,`\thesection` etc., to style the numbering of the various section numbers. You can redefine these to whatever you wish. In the example below, I have redefined the `\thechapter` and `\thesection` to remove the dot and the objectionable zero. This way you can still keep on using the `\chapter` command and you will have no problems with the Table of Contents. I personally dislike the use of star commands as they are very unsemantic if one can coin such a word.

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter title}
\section{A section}
\begin{thm} A theorem \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

I have also removed the word chapter as it is meaningless, if there is no number.

If you want to number the sections with chapter numbers (but not show them in the Chapter head), use:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
```

I am not too sure if this is a good idea though, as it will be confusing to the reader and have never seen such a style in any book.

[image]