# How to Number Theorems within a Chapter?

Tags: numbering, theorems

There are lots of theorems and lemmas in my thesis which are being numbered continuously from start to end. I want the numbering to be like                  Theorem <>.<>. Same for lemmas and corollaries. I am using amsthm and the environments are defined like

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
```

Is there any simple way to get chapter-wise numbering?

Comment: Related: [Numbering theorems within chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53737/numbering-theorems-within-chapters)

Comment: @Papiro The linked answer doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to show another possibility in case.... <sub>(We like hard ways ;)...)</sub>

This can also be done with `chngcntr` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{theorem}{chapter}
\counterwithin{definition}{chapter}
\counterwithin{lemma}{chapter}
\begin{document}

\chapter{1st chapter}

\begin{theorem}
  A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
  A definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{lemma}
  A lemma.
\end{lemma}

\chapter{2nd chapter}

\begin{theorem}
  A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
  Another definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{lemma}
  Another lemma.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One should go Karl's way though :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine for environments except theorem, which is an inbuilt environment. When I add \counterwithin{theorem}{chapter}                         to my preamble, I get error saying theorem is not a counter.

Comment: @Barman It works for theorems too. See the edit. :)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you want your theorem-like environments to be numbered within chapters.

To do this, you have to add the optional parameter `chapter` to your theorem definitions, for example:

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
```

In this way their number contains the chapter number and the numeration is reset at every chapter.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{1st chapter}

\begin{definition}
  A definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{lemma}
  A lemma.
\end{lemma}

\chapter{2nd chapter}

\begin{definition}
  Another definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{lemma}
  Another lemma.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I want it for theorem like environments and theorems as well. How do I do it for the theorem environment which is already defined?

Comment: @Barman, something like `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]`

Comment: \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} says the environment is already defined and gives error. The same problem with @Harish's answer as well.

Comment: Can you please add a MWE in your question?